# __imp__fmode not found in VC++ 2015 Linker

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, linker

I'm trying to upgrade a VS2010 CPP project to VS2015, but i'm stuck on a final unresolved symbol. To resolve other issues I already added the following code and libraries:

> extern "C" { FILE __iob_func[3] = { *stdin,*stdout,*stderr }; }

Added dependencies

> msvcrt.lib vcruntime.lib ucrt.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

Remaining error:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp__fmode

any idea on how i can resolve the missing external reference of __imp__fmode by an external dll which is compiled into the project?

**EDIT**

I set the following which seems to work. Can somebody confirm whether this is correct or how I can check this? I just return '0' because I found a code example for fmode that is always set to 0. But there is no real proof that returning a single integer array with just 0 is the correct implementation.

> extern "C" { unsigned int* __imp__fmode[1] = { 0 }; }